# UIView inside UITableView does not show in runtime

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I have an UITableViewController with UI in a storyboard file. I have drag-and-dropped an UIView on top of the UITableView. It looks great in Interface Builder, but doesn't show at all in runtime:

[image: UIView inside UITableView]

Any hints on how to solve?

**UPDATE:** My project is loosely based on this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-core-data-buildpack-app#add-new-tasks - but one of the differences is that the tutorial uses a NIB file and I have a Storyboard file.

Comment: That should work, but it will scroll up with the table. You don't see it above the first row?

Comment: No, if I force drag the table down, it's just white.

Comment: Why bother wit a UITableViewController, you could use a UIViewController + UIView + UITableView.

Comment: @danypata: Maybe that's the way to go, but it DOES work in this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ios-core-data-buildpack-app#add-new-tasks - the only difference I can see is the use of a NIB file instead of a Storyboard.

Comment: I tried it in a storyboard, and my list of objects in my scene looks just like yours -- mine worked, although I can't scroll the table until I rotate the device, which is weird.

Comment: @rdelmar: Interesting! Sounds like some kind of refresh that doesn't happen, or happens too early.

Comment: It seems to be an auto layout problem. If I turn that off, it scrolls properly. I can also fix it by setting the table's contentSize in viewDidAppear. Is your table scrolling?

Comment: Yes, it's scrolling properly. Currently trying @danypata's approach and have an UIViewController as root. That opened up an entirely different can of worms...

Comment: @TomSöderlund but why ? In my opinion is the easiest way to do it. (Ok, you have to set the data source and delegate of your table view)

Comment: @danypata: First my view didn't display at all, now this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618173/my-app-requires-using-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier-why

Comment: @TomSöderlund sorry I didn't want to cause you trouble.

Comment: No worries @danypata! I think your way is the right one.

Comment: I restarted the project from the MasterDetail template and patching in the AFNetworking bits. Feels like a better foundation. Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bringToFront method in viewDidLoad:

```
[tableView bringSubviewToFront:view];
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added `[self.tableView bringSubviewToFront:self.activityInputView];` to `viewDidLoad`, and made a drag-drop reference between the UIView in Interface Builder and the `activityInputView` @property. Still doesn't show though.