# My app requires using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier - why?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I have added a Storyboard file to an app that initially had none. For some reason, I could not get my custom UIViewController to display correctly until I added this into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
ActivityViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ActivityViewController"];
```

Why do I need to *force* the use of my storyboard like this? The iOS template projects (Single View, Master-Detail etc) doesn't need this.

#### Checklist:

- Xcode Project Summary→Main Storyboard is set correctly to "MainStoryboard".
- Interface Builder→Identity Inspector→Class is correctly set to "ActivityViewController".
- Interface Builder→Identity Inspector→Storyboard ID is also set to "ActivityViewController", but this is only because it's needed by `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

Comment: Does the controller have the arrow pointing to it from the left?

Comment: Yup, and clicking it opens `ActivityViewController.h` as expected.

Comment: Is the Main storyboard file base name set to MainStoryboard in the info.plist?

Comment: Yes. I think it's this property that Xcode Project Summary→Main Storyboard sets.

Comment: This is the second question you asked, where there seems to be something weird with your storyboard. I wonder if there's something wrong with your Xcode.

Comment: @TomSöderlund Could you show some screen shots? Show the storyboard so we can see its name and the Is Initial View Controller setting. Show the info.plist so we can see that the main storyboard is correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to call instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier if you set `Is Initial View Controller` on your "ActivetyViewController" in the storyboard. The initial view controller will have an arrow pointing at it.

[image]